# Simple if statement not working (string comparison)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, collate

This block of code is not working:

```
DECLARE @CollationName varchar(50)
set @CollationName = (
    select collation_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'MeteringPointPrice' and column_name = 'MeteringPointId'
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MPLIST2') IS NOT NULL
    drop table #MPLIST2
if @CollationName = 'SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS'
    create table #MPLIST2 (MeteringPointId varchar(18) COLLATE SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS)
if @CollationName = 'Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS'
    create table #MPLIST2(MeteringPointId varchar(18) COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS)

select @CollationName gives: Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS
```

But both if statements are run so the temporary table #MPLIST2 is created 2 times, which of course gives an error.

I cannot figure out why.

Here is the code changed a little bit:

```
DECLARE @CollationName varchar(50)
set @CollationName = (
    select collation_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'MeteringPointPrice' and column_name = 'MeteringPointId'
)


if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MPLIST2') IS NOT NULL
    drop table #MPLIST2

if @CollationName = 'Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS'
    begin
        create table #MPLIST2 (MeteringPointId varchar(18) COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS)
    end

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MPLIST2') IS NULL
    begin
        select 'hellooo'
        --create table #MPLIST2 (MeteringPointId varchar(18) COLLATE SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS)
    end
```

This part executes succesfully without 'hellooo'. But if I comment in the "create table' line below, then it gives the error "There is already an object named '#MPLIST2' in the database."

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: If there already is a table with that name, maybe you should drop it before recreating it ;.-)

Comment: Jarlh, sorry. It is tsql.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because the entire statement is compiled at the same time.  So, conditions that create an existing table (for instance) cause an error.  One solution is dynamic SQL, but that is messy.  Another is to simply use `GO`:

```
DECLARE @CollationName varchar(50)
set @CollationName = (
    select collation_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'MeteringPointPrice' and column_name = 'MeteringPointId'
)
GO

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MPLIST2') IS NOT NULL
    drop table #MPLIST2
GO

if @CollationName = 'Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS'
    begin
        create table #MPLIST2 (MeteringPointId varchar(18) COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS)
    end;
GO

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MPLIST2') IS NULL
    begin
        select 'hellooo'
        --create table #MPLIST2 (MeteringPointId varchar(18) COLLATE SQL_Danish_Pref_CP1_CI_AS)
    end
GO
```

This generates separate transaction batches in the script, which prevent the error.